# Objective C - Basic question?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use 'self.' when its not forced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120677/why-use-self-when-its-not-forced)

What is the difference between these 2 blocks of code?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *myObject;

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
self.myObject = obj;
[obj release];

MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
myObject = obj;
[obj release];
```

EDIT:

**Does it mean that on the second block I don't need to release "obj" ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `self.myObject` implies that `myObject` is a `@property`, and when you assign to it with `self.myObject = obj`, that property's setter will get invoked. Often, that setter is automagically generated by the compiler with the `@synthesize` directive. If that property's autogenerated setter is flagged with `retain`, then whatever assigned to it (in this case, `obj`) will be retained by the property.

In the second case, `myObject` may or may not be a property. Regardless, this is a simple assignment. No `retain` is done.

Answer (score 0):

The first one calls the accessor of `self`, and the second doesn't.  A logical equivalent for the first block might be:

```
MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
[self setMyObject:obj];
[obj release];
```

As you can see, a method invocation happens there on the second line, which doesn't happen in the second line of your second example.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is used to access class/instance properties (an accessor). For example, if you defined a property in your header file (using `@property`), it is good practice (for code readability amongst other things) to use `self.myClassProperty`. Local variables, like variables declared inside functions (or even outside functions as members), are accessed without the `self` keyword.

Similar SO Question here: [Objective-C - When to use 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385980/objective-c-when-to-use-self)

Answer (score 0):

that depends on how you have declared myObject in your header file. The prevalent practice in the the boilerplate code makes those to semi equivalent.

the difference is that 1 is guaranteed to be using the property named myObject, and therefore will trigger the getter and setter functions.

the second one accessed the the instance variable and is not guaranteed to use the getter and setter functions. if your ivar has the same name as the property it should use the setter and getter functions.

the way to make this more explicit is to prepend something to all of your ivars. (eg mMyObject) and then use a mutator in @synthesize 
    @synthesize myObject = mMyObject;